# python: how to parse string of values like "a = 'abc' b = 'cde' c=13"

Tags: python, string-parsing

Basically if I have a string like `"a = 'abc' b = 'cde' c=13"`, how can I parse it into a dictionary like:

```
{'a': 'abc', 'b': 'cde', 'c': 13}
```

Note that the values can be string literals or numbers, and the string literals can contain equals signs themselves. Spaces outside of the string literals are irrelevant, spaces inside must stay. The string is guaranteed to alternate in the key=value key=value key=value pattern though. Special characters can and will show up inside the string literals, but the keys will be plain alphabetical characters.

Comment: so it could be `"a = 'abc' b = 'cde' c=13 d='asd=123'"` ?

Comment: Can  the values contain spaces? (is `'abc def'` a valid value) What about escaped quotes? (is `'abc\'def'` valid)

Comment: I would guess anything between two single quotes would have to be treated as a value. But OP should really defines the rules for a valid input better to get any decent answers. A list of example inputs and expected outputs would also be nice

Comment: yes, anything inside the quotes has to stay. That includes '=', '\'', ' ', etc.

Comment: So no escaped quote marks then?

Comment: escaped quotes are valid so `"a ='ab\'c'"` has to go to `{'a' : 'ab\'c'}` or `{'a' : "ab'c"}`

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Where/how do you get such strings? I'd probably try to fix the source rather than its output.

Comment: they come from html element tags, but xml parsers don't work because they want to load an entire tree into memory and I only need/have the tag itself

Comment: @kelvinsong You should've started with that description. There's no reason you can't parse a single tag. If it doesn't work then that's a different question about xml/html parser usage. Handcrafted parsers will not match what you need in this case. For this case you need to resolve xml entities as well.

Answer (score 1):

With pyparsing:

```
from pyparsing import Word, Suppress, CharsNotIn, nums, alphanums, dictOf

int_value = Word(nums)
str_value = Suppress("'") + CharsNotIn("'") + Suppress("'")
value = int_value | str_value
identifier = Word(alphanums)
result = dictOf(identifier + Suppress("="), value)

pr = result.parseString("a = 'abc' b = 'cde' c=13")
print(pr.asDict())

# {'a': 'abc', 'b': 'cde', 'c': '13'}
```

This does not take escaped single quotes into account, so you'll have to add that. There's a documentation about it somewhere on the pyparsing website.

Comment: this works if the string literals are only single quotes or double quotes, but not a mixture. So `"a=\"abc\" b='cde'"` fails

Comment: 1. `"` was not mentioned in the question. 2. this is a sample solution - you can easily extend it to support both double quotes and quote escaping - check out the pyparsing docs on how to do that

Comment: This code doesn't actually work, just like the previous three answers.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 You'll have to post the specific error - the code as presented works just fine here.

Comment: As the OP said above, it fails with mixed quote types. As the question specifies string literals and special characters, that is something it should be able to handle.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 The question shows only single-quoted example, so that's what is available in the answer; the double-quotes were mentioned only in a comment here. I can't guess what kelvinsong wants if he doesn't write it in the first place. But that's irrelevant anyway - StackOverflow is not a "write my code for me" service. It would take another line to implement double-quote handling. It would take 5 minutes with the pyparsing documentation to implement escaped quotes. I'm not going to do that - I showed what the solution can look like - the details are for the OP to implement.